# Number of triangles after tessellation

Tags: graphics, directx

I have implemented several Level of Detail techniques to do a comparison between them. Since two of them use tessellation I would like to know how many triangles the final rendered mesh has. I found someone who created a function for doing this, but it only worked if the tessellation factors were constant and all the same. As my implementation decides the factors in the Hull shader based on distance from the camera, his solution does not work for me.

It would seem to me that if I knew how many times the Domain shader was run, then I would know how many triangles I have? Is there a way to count that? Or is there any other way?

(I use DirectX, but I guess the method would be about the same for OpenGL, which is why I have both as tags)

Comment: I don't think you can count the number of vertices a draw command involving a tessellation shader will create without actually running shader and executing the draw commands.

Comment: But I am running the shader and exectuting the draw command, so how can I get the number then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using an ID3D11Query of the type D3D11_QUERY_PIPELINE_STATISTICS. The struct D3D11_QUERY_DATA_PIPELINE_STATISTICS is used for the result, and it has a lot of useful information like number of rendered primitives and invocations of the shaders etc.